# How to recover from a crash during import into Lightroom 5?

Tags: lightroom, import

I was importing images, when my pc blacked out due to overheating. At the time of restarting the import I could still see the images in the explorer (WIN8) and in the import dialogue. The import goes seemingly smoothly without any error messages. The problem is that the images are not shown within LR.

The previews seem fine in the import dialogue, but does not render inside LR5. I have tried to copy-import and add-import. I'm stumped at what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hope that the only files corrupted are those that were being copied; since you don't delete the file from the card until after the file is verified to be written correctly, you can

- repair the file system
- re-copy *all* the files from the card, including those that are already there, since the old copy may be bad abd the copy-over is OK.
- fix the LR database by restoring from backup and re-importing everything after that.

I think the image file themselves are not a problem; it's the mysterious LR database that is worrisome. Do you need it for anything? I find its imposition of a database to be an unnecessary complication, and I keep the XMP files in the same directory as the image.

That's the point I want to add: the directory with image files and work files should be self contained and usable without strange stuff in other locations. That facilitates backups and moving stuff to archival storage and *reading* old archives too.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting existing .xmp-files created during the interrupted and attempted import, and reinstallation of LR solved the issue.

Comment: that is a horrible fix...